# BigCommerce and Development / Optimization

Tags: optimization, bigcommerce

We have a BigCommerce website that's scoring very poorly in GTMetrix ("E") for PageSpeed and YSlow (https://www.dogids.com). The list of items that are killing our performance are items I know how to easily fix on a WordPress website, but I'm not sure what the limitations are for BigCommerce as it sounds like their platform works more like Shopify in that you're limited to template files.

**THE QUESTION**
If you've developed and optimized a BigCommerce site, could you let me know if these optimizations are possible?

1. JS and CSS minification (important)
2. **Defer JavaScript** (important)
3. Expiry Headers
4. Caching rules
5. Optimizing the order of styles or scripts
6. Making fewer HTTP requests (45 external calls)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. JS and CSS minification (important)

It depends on whether it's part of your theme, or a third party file, what technique you use to minify.
You can always minify a resource.

2. Defer JavaScript (important)

It depends on how the script is added to the site. Theme, Script Manager, and Footer all support specifying async or defer...

3. Expiry Headers

can't be changed

4. Caching rules

can't be changed

5. Optimizing the order of styles or scripts

full control

6. Making fewer HTTP requests (45 external calls)

you can control this to some extent, by combining scripts and stylesheets manually.
part of this is a factor of how many external scripts you have from apps, analytics tracking, et al.

Best bang for your buck. Get yourself a good End User Monitoring tool, and use the metrics of how quickly your page is rendered. That's the only metric that matters to a user.

- https://raygun.com/platform/real-user-monitoring
- https://www.appdynamics.com/product/end-user-monitoring/
- https://newrelic.com/products/browser-monitoring

Comment: That's what I needed to know. Thank you kindly!

Comment: Technically, Expiry Headers, Caching Rules and about everything else can be changed if you're using a reverse-proxy in front of your store. I haven't tested this, but in theory, it's possible.